# Google Sheets How to find the Top 3 closest columns to a given column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a table in google sheets like this one,

```
-------------------
   | A | B | C | D |
-------------------
1  |C1 |C2 |C3 |C4 |
2  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
3  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
4  | 5 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
-------------------
```

My goal is to find which 2 columns C1,C2,C3 are closest to C4,

by calculate the average difference bewteen each column and column C4,

e,g Column C1 will have an averyage of abs( (  (1-2)+(2-3)+(5-6)  )  /3 )

which is , abs( (  (A2-D2)+(A3-D3)+(A4-D4) )/(number of rows) )

I'm using ARRYFORMULA to get the average differece for one column and then I drag it horizontally so As will increase to Bs and so on

`=ArrayFormula({A1;abs(average(  (checks if there is empty cell)  ,$D2:$D-(A2:A) )))})`

if I use it in cell Z1, Z1 will show 'C1', and Z2 will show the average difference for column C1

but i'm not sure how to use a single nested formula to do it for all columns A:C  at once, with out having to drag it

like I if I type `=FORMULA(...)` in Z1, and a table will show up

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(ABS((ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C))^0*D2:D26-A2:C26)),
"select avg(Col"&JOIN("), avg(Col",ArrayFormula(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(A2:C)))))&")")`

**Explanation**

- `(ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C))^0*D2:D26` -- copy C4 to compare it with others
- `"select avg(Col"&JOIN("), avg(Col"...` -- compose query to get the average for each column.

---

Note: in your formula `abs(average(` must be replaced → `average(abs(` in order to complete `abs` function first.